# update RemoteViews in notification every second

Tags: java, android, android-remoteview

I have a problem with updating custom notification value in my service.
I use RemoteView and want to update textview every second and I don't have any true idea for doing this.
it's my code:

```
int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

Notification notification = new Notification(icon, "Custom Notification", when);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notificationview);
contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.ic_launcher); 
contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, "This is a custom layout"); 
contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "Title");
notification.contentView = contentView;

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR; 

startForeground(13, notification);
```

any idea ?

Comment: `update textview every second` - that's very bad idea.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski whats your suggestion for updating notification ?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski What makes it a bad idea? Does it suffer from the same performance issues as widgets? I know that widgets are not recommended at all to update every second, does the same apply to RemoteViews in general, and if so - why?

Comment: in 2015 it could be literally anything, with nasty flickering, performance hit and other things normal back then. it might be not a problem any more as tech advanced still updating things to frequent than it is really needed is always a bad idea and resource waste.

Answer (score 2):

I still haven't completely figured out on how to update the notification text properly BUT what i did notice is that updating TextView in the RemoteView will cause some performance issues and it will also cause the overall ui to slow down quite a lot. Anyways...  after messing around with the notification this is currently what i have:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notiBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(activity);

notiBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentTitle("Sup bro!")
    .setContentText("It works dude!")
    .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "Some Text", pendingAction);

NotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notify);
```

and then you can update the notification text like this:

```
notiBuilder.setContentText("Updating text...");
NotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notify);
```

using this method you shouldn't have any performance issue. I'm still working on it, if i figure something out ill let you know.

Comment: Have you figured out anything new in the past 7 years?